# How do I copy (and map?) a custom lookup field from Leads to Opportunity and to Account

Tags: custom-field, picklist

I have been asked to add a new picklist field on the leads page which I have done but this also needs to follow thru to the opportunities and accounts page if the lead is qualified.  Can someone explain how to do this?

Please reply in layman's language as I'm not at all techy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's what you need to do. Let's assume your Lead field is called Lead Picklist, with an API/System name of Lead_Picklist__c:

1. Create a matching custom field on the Account object, called Account Picklist/Account_Picklist__c. Since you managed to create the Lead field, I'm assuming you can do this part. This field can either be a picklist as well, with matching picklist values, or a text field. If you want to be able to change it according to the values, use a picklist.
2. Create a **formula** field on Opportunity. Same as creating the other fields, except first you indicate that it's a formula field, and then you give the data type of the formula - in this case, Text. If your Account field is a picklist, the value of your formula field will be: TEXT(Account.Account_Picklist__c). If your Account field is a text field, then you can use just Account.Account_Picklist__c.
3. Map your Lead field to your Account field. Setup > Customize > Leads > Fields. At the top of the Lead Custom Fields & Relationships list, click the "Map Lead Fields" button. Find your Lead Picklist field and select your Account.Account Picklist field from the corresponding drop-down. Click save.

Now, when you convert a lead, your Lead Picklist field will be copied over to the new Account, and will appear on the Opportunity via the formula field.

Comment: Hi Thomas! Aha! Step by step instructions... but I have come unstuck!  I did step 1 OK although I realised it was a multiple picklist I used in the leads. Does this make a difference?  

Step 2 - when I try to put the formula field in (I presume I put this in on "Step 3: Enter formula" in the bottom field?) It says "Error: Field Account_Picklist_c does not exist. Check spelling." 

Where have I gone wrong already?

Comment: Did you make the Account field multi-select as well? Also, my instructions used sample field names - you should use field names appropriate to your business throughout. Multi-selects are kind of a pain, especially in formulas - skip step 2 for now and get the mapping working.

Comment: Hi Yes I realised that afterwards!  I did make it as a multi-select and the field is for "Services Picklist" so the API bit is "Services_Picklist__c" correct? OK So I'll try Step 3.

Comment: Woohoo!  Account bit worked! :D  Thanks Just have to figure out the Opportunity bit now!

Comment: As I said, formulas with multi-selects are a pain, but here's how you do it. For a multi-select whose possible values are Red, Blue, Purple & Green, this formula returns a list on separate lines: 
`IF(INCLUDES(Account.Color__c,"Red"),"Red" & BR(),"") & 
IF(INCLUDES(Account.Color__c,"Blue"),"Blue" & BR(),"") & 
IF(INCLUDES(Account.Color__c,"Purple"),"Purple" & BR(),"") & 
IF(INCLUDES(Account.Color__c,"Green"),"Green","")`
If you want a semi-colon delimited list, change each line to, eg, `IF(INCLUDES(Account.Color__c,"Red"),"Red; ","")`
(avoiding the trailing semi-colon is a lot more work)

Comment: Hmmm, that looks way complicated!! I think I better ask a colleague who is hot on  Excel to look at your reply. I'm sure he will be able to work it out.  Thank you very much for your help Thomas!

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you in layman's language ,

The requirement is to copy the picklist value to opportunity and Account once the lead is converted .

One way to achieve this will be a simple trigger ,when Lead is converted copy the field values from the Lead Picklist to fields created on account and opportunity .

> Out of box will be to use Leads mapping and copy to Account Field and then use trigger or workflow to pull the value from opportunity attached

Please note above answer assumes that we have picklist on Opportunity and Account

Comment: Suggesting a trigger when there is an out-of-the-box feature is not using layman's terms.

Comment: If your field on Account and opportunity is picklist then formula field wont work

Comment: Not sure who downvoted my answer .Any reason now to downvote after i clarify

Comment: Thanks Mohith but I didn't really understand this :( Need step by step instructions!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a formula field with your formula being the contents of the field you want to display on you the opportunities and accounts page. Here's an example of my formula looks like for adding the site field from my Account object to a custom object.

```
 Account_Owner__r.Site
```

Comment: Thanks also but I don't understand this either! Need step by step instructions1